# Currency String Formatting

Tags: c#, formatting, currency

I am a student in school for c# and have been given a problem to solve. Within the problem, you have to format currency. I have figured out how to format $, but still have yet to figure out Yen, and Baht.

```
            int num1;
            string fNum;
            string aNum;

            num1 = 1255;
            fNum = num1.ToString("C"); //  "C" Changes Number to $$
            aNum = "US:";
            Console.WriteLine(aNum + fNum);
```

This has given me 
US : $1,255.00 .

How do I format BAHT and YEN?

Comment: you may need to create a new cultureinfo object for each currency, but please remember that SO is no place to get your homework done by others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an overload of `ToString()` and into second parameter `culture` pass specific culture for Yen and Baht.

Here is an example for `$` and `£`

```
specifier = "C";
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(specifier, culture));
// Displays:    $16,325.62
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(specifier, culture));
// Displays:    £16,325.62
```

Source: [Decimal to string help](https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Decimal_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the namespace:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

then add:

```
string jp = num.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("ja-JP"));
```

For the baht is the same just change the symbols.